# Why do the concepts of linear algebra apply to differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

A lot of the stuff we do to solve differential equations are taken word for word from linear algebra. The concept of linear independence, determinant of the Wronskian used to determine independence, adding a particular solution to the kernel to get the general solution - all this stuff that I'm used to applying on vectors seems to work with functions. Why?

Comment: More importantly, which came first ?

Comment: I've always considered the use of linear algebra in differential equations to be a matter of the use of computers today to solve differential equations. When I took my numerical analysis course, this really started showing itself, [as I even ended up making an entire library of python commands](https://github.com/Twoody/Lin_Alg_py) just to solve all of the differential equations we were working with.

Comment: @T.Woody The use of linear algebra in differential equations is much older than electronic computers.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, This is true! However, the inclination of bringing back all of the linear algebra, and old techniques of solving things has a large to do with how computers work and operate.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus  The answer to your question seems to be that the differential equations came first.  Euler did a lot of work on linear differential equations in the mid-18th century, and D'Alembert essentially invented eigenvalues in the context of linear differential equations (for vibrating strings) in the same time period.  Matrices (as opposed to determinants) appeared  in the mid-19th century, and the general concept of a (real) linear space was only introduced by Peano in 1888.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because differentiation is a linear operator, and hence can be represented by a matrix acting on a function.

**Specific example for OP**

$f''+3f'+2f=0 \implies f=ae^{x}+be^{2x}\equiv (a,b)\cdot(e^{x},e^{2x})\equiv \mathbf{a\cdot f}$

Therefore, the solutions to the differential equations can be represented as *vectors* in a *function space* with the basis $(e^{x},e^{2x})$

**Second Addition**

As you can see by all the answers on this page, solutions to linear ODEs can be represented by vectors in the space of functions. If you want more details, you can check out [this nice paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/diffeqdim.pdf).

Comment: How can a operator be represented as a matrix? A matrix is a collection of discrete values - how is that related to a derivative?

Comment: When the operator has a finite-dimensional invariant subspace, it can be represented as a matrix with respect to a basis of the subspace.

Comment: You're thinking about it too concretely. Imagine you have a solution to a 3rd-order linear ODE. This will have three characteristic roots and three associated functions. Now, in elementary linear algebra, you can represent a space with "unit vector" components (i,j,k, usually). Instead, replace these unit vectors by the solutions to the differential equation. Now, the space of solutions to the equation is the "space" spanned by a real-valued vector (in 3 dimensions) whose components specify a particular linear combination of these "basis functions"

Comment: @dfg see my explanation above and my edit to the post.

Comment: The fact that the differentiation is a linear operator does not help at all to solve anything like $\dot x=x^2$.

Comment: @Artem This is true but irrelevant; linear algebraic methods are only indirectly related to nonlinear problems.

Comment: @Artem Well...its saying that the complementary function is the trivial $\mathbf{0}$ with particular solution $x=\frac{-1}{t}$. However, the concepts the OP is discussing clearly indicates systems of homogenous LODEs and their particular solutions, to which the linearity of the operator is essential

Comment: This idea about differentiation as a matrix is made much more concrete with the Fourier transform, because in Fourier space the differentiation operator is essentially a diagonal matrix. Indeed it is *exactly* an infinite diagonal matrix on, say, $C^1[a,b]$.

Comment: @Ian agreed...but I didn't want to go there....you can see it already in how to construct solutions to homogenous linear ODEs

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Yes, OP actually alludes to linear systems. And (my point) the fact that differentiation is a linear operator does not have to do anything with the original question.

Comment: @Artem *"linear independence, determinant of the Wronskian used to determine independence, adding a particular solution to the kernel to get the general solution"*...what about these things does *not* rely on the linearity of differentiation?

Comment: @dfg see my additon..I've linked to a paper that goes into much more detail about how solutions to linear ODEs form a vector space.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Thank you, your answer was perfect. Appreciate the link to the paper!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple application of the theory of linear algebra to differential equations.

Consider the differential equation
$$
y^{\prime\prime}+y=0\tag{1}
$$
How do we find all of the solutions to (1)? We know that (1) is solved by both $y=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$ but are there any other solutions?

To answer this question note that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ solve (1) and if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are scalars, then
$$
y=\lambda_1\cdot y_1+\lambda_2\cdot y_2
$$
is also a solution to (1). This means that the collection $V$ of all solutions to (1) is a *vector space*. In fact, one may show that $\dim V=2$ and that $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are linearly independent solutions to (1). Hence all solutions to (1) are of the form
$$
\lambda_1\cdot\cos(t)+\lambda_2\cdot \sin(t)
$$
for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\Bbb R$.

More generally, one may show that the collection of solutions $V$ to a differential equation of the form
$$
a_n\cdot y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}\cdot y^{(n-1)}+\dotsb+a_1\cdot y^\prime+a_0\cdot y=0\tag{2}
$$
is a vector space with $\dim V=n$. So, to find all solutions to (2) we need only find $n$ linearly independent solutions to (2).